# Setting initial value for md-select

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am using Angular Material `2.0.0-beta.8`. I know this is an old version but upgrading is not an option at the moment.

For the  element I want to define a pre selected entry.

```
<md-select>
  <md-option *ngFor="let amount of items" [value]="amount">
    {{amount}}
  </md-option>
</md-select>
```

The content of `items` is for example `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`.

Now I want to pre select `4` if the component is rendered.

I would expect that I can use `[(ngModel)]` as it is also described in the select markdown file. But for some reason I get the following error `Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'md-select'.` I can't find the `ngModel` `@Input` in the source code.

Is there a way to pre select an entry? And yes, how can I achieve this?

Comment: did you import the FormModule?

Comment: Yes. The FormModule is imported and working. FormValidation and other stuff is working well.

Comment: @Sören Where did you import it?